# When second condition is met, first condition fails

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I only want to keep the rows in a Pandas DataFrame meeting the following conditions:

1) Users should have interacted with more than X items
2) Items should have interacted with more than Y users

When the second condition is met, after applying both conditions, for some users the first condition fail.

```
groupById = df.groupby(['id']).count()
remaining = groupById[groupById.itemId > X]
df2 = df.loc[df.id.isin(remaining.index)]

groupByItem = df2.groupby(['id']).count()
remainingIt = groupByItem[groupByItem.id > Y]
final = df[df.id.isin(remaining.index) & df.itemId.isin(remainingIt.index)]
```

I can't get my head around this recursive-ish problem. Anyone?

Comment: How are you determining that the first condition fails?

Comment: Maybe when you calculate the first condition, you use all the items (before filtering), and after you filter you obviously have less items so the first condition might fail

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you group on items after removing users that did not interact more than X times. You first need to check independently on both conditions and only then combine the results.
    `import pandas as pd`

```
#set threshold X and Y
X=1
Y=2
#fill dataframe with some users and items
users=pd.Series(['U1','U1','U1','U2'])
items=pd.Series(['Y1','Y2','Y3','Y1'])
frame=pd.DataFrame()
frame['user'] = users.values
frame['item'] = items.values
  user item
0   U1   Y1
1   U1   Y2
2   U1   Y3
3   U2   Y1

#groupby item and user
groupByItem=frame.groupby('item').count().reset_index()
groupByUser=frame.groupby('user').count().reset_index()
item  user
0   Y1     2
1   Y2     1
2   Y3     1
  user  item
0   U1     3
1   U2     1

#filter both on condition
filteredItems=groupByItem.loc[groupByItem['user']>X]
filteredUsers=groupByUser.loc[groupByUser['item']>Y]

#only take records where both user and items appear in filtered list
print(frame[frame['user'].isin(filteredUsers.user) & frame['item'].isin(filteredItems.item)])

  user item
0   U1   Y1
```

Hope this helps